# Generate informatica mappings to save development effort

Tags: informatica

I have 100 files on amazon s3 in various folders under 5 different buckets which need to load in snowflake 100 different target tables. I can import physical source and target objects, build pipelines manually which will take long time for me.

Is there is any alternate way to generate 100 mappings using some script or command to save development effort.

I am using Informatica developer 10.2 version.

Comment: You can check the [Mapping Architect for Visio](https://kb.informatica.com/proddocs/Product%20Documentation/4/PC_100_MappingArchitectForVisioGuide_en.pdf). There are also a few mapping generators available at https://marketplace.informatica.com/.

Comment: Is this a one time effort?

Comment: @mdem7 yes this is one time development effort.

Comment: If it's a one time effort why don't you create an s3 connector and use COPY command to load the files.

Comment: oh, sorry, I need to move to production and execute on daily basis.